# Admin-ajax on theme live preview WordPress page doesn't work

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress

In my WordPress theme I use AJAX to get post content using `admin-ajax.php` file. But in my theme live preview this file always returns 0. Why? I use `.ajax()` jQuery function. Action parameter is correct. URL to `admin-ajax` file is correct, too. On normal site it works all fine. Is this a bug in Wordpress?
The code of php function and js function is very simple:
PHP

```
add_action('wp_ajax_ajax_response', 'ajax_response');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_ajax_response' ,'ajax_response');
function ajax_response() {
 echo 'This is server response';
}
```

JS

```
jQuery.ajax({
 type:"GET",
 url: ajaxInfo.admin_ajax_url,
 data:{"action":"ajax_response"},
 success:function(results){console.log(results);} 
}
```

I have localize ajaxInfo object via wp_localize_script.

Comment: Can you check in your console if the POST request is ok ?

Comment: Yep, I chceck it and when i am on the live preview page is POST request same as POST request on normal page.

Comment: please post the code for your ajax function from functions.php